# Vaadin Java: Import problem with css file

Tags: java, css, vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin10

I´m working on the Vaadin Tutorial series part 8

Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ttuBu8dYNn0

Text Version: https://vaadin.com/learn/tutorials/modern-web-apps-with-spring-boot-and-vaadin/creating-custom-reusable-components-in-vaadin?medium=social

Therefore I´m struggling with the last step of importing the given css file. I do exactly the same as in the tutorial shown but the form style doesn´t change. It seems the css file is not working.

Vaadin Version 14.4.2

My Project folder incl. MainView:

[image]

CSS File:

```
/* List view */
.list-view .content {
    display: flex;
}

.list-view .contact-grid {
    flex: 2;
}

.list-view .contact-form {
    flex: 1;
    padding: var(--lumo-space-m);
}

@media all and (max-width: 1100px) {
    .list-view.editing .toolbar,
    .list-view.editing .contact-grid {
        display: none;
   }
}
```

My WebApp

[image]

Should be like this:

[image]

Comment: @BasilBourque Please check edited Questions. The Version seems not clearly defined.

Answer (score 0):

Solved after I added the following dependency regarding to a other issue:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```